# How to add keys to array you render in React

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-ui

My problem is that Menu from Material UI wont let me group `<MenuItem />`'s in a `<React.Fragment />` like this:

```
<Menu>
  <React.Fragment>
    <MenuItem />
    <MenuItem />
    <MenuItem />
  </React.Fragment>
</Menu>
```

. If I do that, I get this error message:

`Warning: Material-UI: the MenuList component doesn't accept a Fragment as a child.
Consider providing an array instead.`

So because of this I tried to add all my `<MenuItem />`'s to an array this way:

```
const menuItems = [];
menuItems.push(<MenuItem />);
menuItems.push(<MenuItem />);
menuItems.push(<MenuItem />);
```

and then in the render I do this:

```
render() {
  const menuItems = [];
  ...
  return (
    <Menu>
      {menuItems}
    </Menu>
  );
}
```

And this works fine. It renders all my `<MenuItem />`'s, but I get this warning, which I would like to fix:

`warning.js:33 Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.`

Comment: You don't want to wrap you `MenuItem`s in a `Menu` directly? `<Menu><MenuItem /> ... </Menu>`

Comment: simply remove the Fragment and pass the key prop to the MenuItem

Comment: You can just specify a key parameter as the length of the menuItems for every MenuItem. Ex: menuItems.push(<MenuItem key={menuItems.length} />);

Comment: The reason I want to wrap MenuItem inside a React.Fragment is because some MenuItems should be visible in the Menu if you have a specific flag, and this would be more readable. AbsoluteSith's answer worked well!